# Mongoose Updating document without even running save() function

Tags: mongoose, document, updating

I am using express. 
I have file paths in MongoDb, before sending response from Api.
I am prepending the api Url with the file path
like

```
song.path = url + song.path;
res.send(song);
```

but what this is doing that it updates the path in mongodb as well, even though i am not saving this doc, i amd just sending the response

i have tried

```
const newSong = song;
newSong.path = url + newSong.path;
res.send(newSong)
```

;

but this didnt help, document is still updating.

This is my controller

```
    const song = await Song.findOne({ 'lastPlayed': false }).sort("-totalRating");
    song.lastPlayed = true;
    song.save();
    song.path = url + song.path;
    res.send(song);
```

it should only update the property for response.. not in Db

**UPDATE**

If i comment out `song.save()` path doesnt get updated.

Comment: the song is an instance of a model if you are going to save it, as it has all the necessary fields including change and id, it is going to update it. If you want to change only response, do not make a save call here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that `doc.save()` is asynchronous, when you mutate the object and send the response `doc.save()` only execute after the main thread that is why `song.path = url + song.path;` gets copy to mongoDB even though you think you save it before.

you can create a new object just for the response

```
const song = await Song.findOne({ 'lastPlayed': false }).sort("-totalRating");
song.lastPlayed = true;
song.save();
res.send({ ...song, path: url + song.path });
```

Or you can `await` the save and then mutate the object for your response, this is good if you want to handle errors before sending the response.

```
const song = await Song.findOne({ 'lastPlayed': false }).sort("-totalRating");
song.lastPlayed = true;
await song.save();
song.path = url + song.path;
res.send(song);
```